# Filter certain instrument/sound from track

Tags: filter, adobe-audition

I'd like to eliminate a certain sound from a track, namely the one produced by cymbale. Take a look at it:

https://vocaroo.com/i/s1FpZrxM07TK

It has a very unique signature compared to the surrounding frequencies(my cursor is where track beat starts):

[image]

But simply erasing the sound make the track sound a little muffled

[image]

What technique do you recommend that I use? The sound is extremely popular across stock music authors, but unfortunately I need to get rid of it. I am pretty new at sound design and I am using Adobe Audition. Am I using the correct tool for the task?

Answer (score 1):

Because a cymbal like that has a really wide frequency spectrum you are not going to be able to remove it from an audio track. Instead, replacement with an equivalent audio sample minus the cymbal is the way to go, or recreate the sample from scratch without cymbals.

Sorry - it just can't be done. Removal tools cope okay with single frequencies, and noise removal tools work well on repetitive noise, but this is currently too challenging.

Answer (score 0):

I can guess that tune in 4 notes, coldplay...
I bet you can find the midi of this tune and via a free DAW replicate the song sans cymbals.